# Comparison of one dimensional int array with multidimensional object array

Tags: php, arrays

before I even start I want to apologize for maybe easy problem for you since I am kinda new into this. So let's get straight to the point.

I have massively huge multidimensional array (it's a tree of categories and each category has another category inside and another and another, etc). This whole array actually contains objects (every key is instance of 'category' object) so it has everything inside (Id, parentId, children(array) etc).

I have also my second array which is simple array of IDs (one dimensional array, only with numbers - IDs of categories).

Now I am trying to find those few IDs from my second array in the tree and get (as result of this comparison) the lowest ID in each branch of tree.

For really simple example (sorry it's really hard to explain):

Tree array:

- 1

  - 5

    - 7
    - 11

      - 12
  - 6
- 2
- 3
- 4

  - 8

    - 13
  - 9
  - 10

And in my second array is the WHOLE route to category I need + another routes, for example:

```
[1] = 1,
[5] = 5,
[11] = 11,
[12] = 12,
[4] = 4,
[8] = 8
```

And I need to get ONLY the last category of the branch THAT I HAVE IN SECOND ARRAY, so here the result should be **12** and **8** because they are the last elements in their branches if you get what I mean it... it doesn't have to be leaf.

Thank you for any ideas!!

//Edit: I forgot about showing what I was trying indeed I am really sorry, here we go:

```
    private function buildRows($products): array {
    $export = [ ]; // final array ($row)
    foreach ( $products as $product ) {
        $producer = $this->producers [$product->getProducerId ()];
        foreach ( $product->getSpecies () as $specie ) {
            $data = [ 
                    'id' => $product->getId (),
                    'url_vyrobce' => $producer->getUrl ()
            ];
            $tempUrl  = $producer->getUrl();
            foreach ( $this->csvRegions as $headCode ) {
                foreach ( $product->getRegions () as $region ) {
                    $data [$region->getRegionCode () . '_name'] = $region->getName ();
                }
            }

            $data ['catalog_no'] = $product->getCatalogNo ();
            $data ['catalog_no_suffix'] = $specie->getSuffix ();

            $productCategories = $product->getCategories(); 
            $leaf = [];
            $leaf[] = $this->findCategoryLeaves($product->getCategories(), $this->categoryTree);
            dump($leaf);
            foreach ( $productCategories as $catId ) {
                //$ids[] = $this->findCategoriesRoot($catId, $this->categoryTree);
                $category = $this->categoryDao->getCategory ( $catId );
                $parentId = $category->getParentCategoryId();
                //$this->categoryDao->loadParents ( $category ); // get parrents for this needle
                /*foreach($this->categoryTree as $key => $cat){
                    if($cat['id'] === $parentId){
                        $parents[] = $key;
                    }
                    dump($parents[]);
                }*/
                /*      
                while ($parent = $category->getParentCategory()) {
                    if (in_array ( $parent->getId(), $productCategories )) {
                        array_push ( $parents, $parent->getId() );
                    }
                    if ($category->getParentCategory()) {
                        $category = $parent;
                    }
                }
                */
            }
            $row = [ ];
            foreach ( $this->createCsvHead () as $col ) {
                if (isset ( $data [$col] )) {
                    $row [] = $data [$col];
                } else {
                    $row [] = '';
                }
            }

            $export [] = $row; 
        }
    }
    return $export;
}
```

Here I was just doing some preperations for CSV file which will be in the end created from data. There is a function I am calling

```
$this->FindCategoryLeaves($product->getCategories, $this->categoryTree)
```

This function is here bellow (it's not finished because I am stucked with the solution. I guess it should be recursive but I can't make it work)

```
private function findCategoryLeaves($productCategory, $categoryTree){
    dump($categoryTree);
    $leaves = [];
    $branches = [];
    dump($productCategory);
    $lastElement = end($productCategory);
    foreach($productCategory as $productCatId){
        foreach($categoryTree as $catTree){
            $catTreeId = $catTree->getId();
            if($catTreeId === $productCatId){
                if($productCatId === $lastElement){ 
                    $branches[] = $productCatId; 
                    dump($catTreeId . ' | LAST ID');
                    findCategoryLeaves($productCategory, $categoryTree); 
                }
                //}else{
                //  $leaves[] = $productCatId;
            }
            dump($catTreeId .' | ID NOT FOUND!');
            /*$subs = $catTree->getSubcategories();
            if(array_key_exists($productCategoryId, $subs)){
                dump($subs);
                $leaf[] = $productCategoryId;
                $this->findCategoryLeaves($productCategoryId, $subs);
            }else{
                dump($leaf);
                return $leaf;
            }*/
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How is `8` the last element of its branch, when you have `13` indented below it?

Comment: Plus, if you want to get help on this site, you are supposed to show us what you have tried so far. Please go read [ask].

Comment: extract ids from multidimensional array using `array_column()` then compare

Comment: @misorude it doesn't has to be the leaf of whole tree branch. Like when you have T-shirt category and it has sub-category of other variants which are optional. Basically for me the 'imaginary leaf' is the last ID I know.

Comment: @misorude plus I am sorry I forgot about showing my code. My very best apologies for that. I have edited the question